# Is it possible to obtain the output of a intermediate layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

If a big model consists of end-to-end individual models, can I (after training) **preserve only one model** and freeze/discard other models during inference?

An example: this *struct2depth* (see below) have three models training in an unsupervised fashion. However, what I really need is the object motion, namely `3D Object Motion Estimation` part. So I wonder if this is feasible to

- `train` on the original networks, but
- `inference` with only `Object Motion Estimator`, i.e. other following layers frozen/discarded?

I saw that in `tensorflow` one can obtain tensor-output of a specified layer, but to save unnecessary computation I'd like to simply freeze all other parts... don't know if it's possible.

Looking forward to some insights. Thanks in advance!

[image: Struct2Depth]

Comment: You mean after training you want to just give *3D object motion detector* input and get its output, forgetting all other part of the network?

Comment: @amin yes exactly! since During inference computation takes places only forwardly right?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a little confused. lets say you have sub_model 1, 2, 3 and your main model is like sub_model_1 -> sub_model_2 -> sub_model_3. now you just need sub_model_2, so why you don't simply give sub_model_2 the input and get the output?

Comment: @amin Because it's self-supervised training. Only with all 3 submodels can I perform training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore weights by setting them to 0. For this, you can directly get a weight `W` and do `W.assign(tf.mul(W,0))`. I know that you care about speeding up inference but unless you rewrite your code to use sparse representations, you will probably not be speeding up inference since weights can't be removed fully.

What you can alternatively do, is look at existing solutions for [pruning in custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/comprehensive_guide#prune_custom_keras_layer_or_modify_parts_of_layer_to_prune):

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Dense, tfmot.sparsity.keras.PrunableLayer):

  def get_prunable_weights(self):
    # Prune bias also, though that usually harms model accuracy too much.
    return [self.kernel, self.bias]

# Use `prune_low_magnitude` to make the `MyDenseLayer` layer train with pruning.
model_for_pruning = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(MyDenseLayer(20, input_shape=input_shape)),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
])
```

You can e.g. use `ConstantSparsity` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/ConstantSparsity)) and set the parameters such that your layers are fully pruned.

Another alternative is to construct a second, smaller model that you only use for inference. You can then save the required weights separately (instead of saving the entire model) after training and load them in the second model.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Actually, I think the last alternative seems promising since I only need that submodel. I will try that:)